# Fetching Gmail Using PHP: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream

Tags: php, gmail-imap

**Preface:**

I've read several StackOverflow threads and have tried virtually all of them.

1. I’m trying to set up IMAP via PHP to fetch some emails using [Clivern/Imap](https://github.com/Clivern/Imap)
2. I've also tried David Walsh's post: [Retrieve Your Gmail Emails Using PHP and IMAP](https://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap)

**Things I have done:**

1. Tried this using both a GSuite and Gmail account; IMAP is enabled on both.
2. Allowed ['Less Secure Apps' to connect](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) (even though I am running under a valid SSL). [OpenSSL is installed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.php/JB5hm8cKi_Q) *(OpenSSL 1.0.2o 27 Mar 2018)*
3. I've completed [Display Unlock Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha)
4. I've tried testing in multiple local/hosted environments

**The Issue:**

1. The connection works when I use GSuite; it fails when I use Gmail (I have checked the email/password multiple times and compared IMAP settings side-by-side...they are all OK)
2. The error I get when attempting to check Gmail via the Clivern Library is: `Warning --> imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX`
3. The error I get when attempting to check Gmail via the PHP functions is: `Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)`

**My Code:**

```
// Using Library
use Clivern\Imap\Core\Connection;
use Clivern\Imap\MailBox;

$imap_email = 'my_email@gmail.com';
$imap_password = 'my_password';

$connection = new Connection(
    "imap.gmail.com",
    "993",
    $imap_email,
    $imap_password,
    "/ssl", // I've also tried /ssl/novalidate-cert
    "INBOX"
);

$connection->connect();
$mailbox = new MailBox($connection);
$folders = $mailbox->getFolders();
echo var_dump($folders);
$connection->disconnect();

// Using PHP functions
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$username = $imap_email;
$password = $imap_password;

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

**My Question:**

What else could be causing Gmail to fail to authenticate?

...I'm particularly confused why GSuite would work and Gmail wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue

It was related to password expiration date.

If you try to login, in incognito - gmail asks you to change password?
If yes, you can change password in gmail and your code - and probably that helps